# Import csv file into Postgresql having value with double quote and comma

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create a table and then import from csv file. There is one column_name's value has double quote and comma, such as "123.45". I set up the type of the column_name as float.

when I import it, the error message shows "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "123,45".

what type should I set up for column_name?

Thanks

I tried to alter the type to numeric and it didn't work.